# How should I catch a change in a bunch of dropdowns (in a table) and store it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table populated with static data, one column contains a dropdown that is built for every row during a `forEach` (item in an array). While they have the same content, they need to be treated separately. The user will change a dropdown and their choice needs to be stored.

I've seen jquery `.change` method, and according to the docs can go like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "input[type='select']" ).change(function() {
        console.log (input( $( this ).val() )
    });
});
```

to fire when there's a change in any of the dropdowns. But the above doesn't log, nor does it error.

How do I monitor all of those dropdowns for changes and store the change?

***OR***

Would I be better off setting a script per `select` to monitor its one assigned element? I'm not concerned about performance or filesize, now or likely ever. I'm already using a `forEach` to populate the rows and `selected` the right `option` of the dropdown

Comment: Change console.log (input( $( this ).val() ) to console.log($(this).val()); and try it again

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're using `select`, **NOT** `input[type="select"]`. That's the incorrect one.

```
<table id="yourTableID">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <select>
             <option value="blahXX">Some Text</option>
             ....
             ....
          </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `input[type="XXX"]` would be:

- input
- password
- email
- etc

What you need is jQuery's `on` event, described below. The difference b/w NOT having the `on` event, and using the `change` event, is that you stated that the selects are "cloned", meaning that the `change` event will NOT be set on these new cloned selects.

Additionally, it's always a good practice to use the below code, regardless if you're using `on`, or another event (such as `change`, `click`, etc.). What this does is says, "Look at this element (usually an ID), and when an event happens, apply it to the elements that are in the function". Rather than say (without using this way), "Take all these XXX elements and add an event listener to each one of them. *Why have XXXX event listeners when you only need one!*

```
$(function() {   <-- this is the same as using (document).ready
    $('#yourTableID').on('change','select', function(e) {
         // your stuff here
    });
});
```

Basically you're only creating 1 event listener, rather than XX. This will only add the listener to the table w/ XX ID, and say, "watch the `selects` within this element with XX ID, and if a `change` event happens, fire the event".

http://api.jquery.com/on/

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(),  .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()

Comment: Couple questions about the text... is b/w to mean "by the way"? b/w usually means "black and white" as far as I've known. Then in your last paragraph, you accidentally a word "This will only the listener to the table w/ XX ID". What's the missing word?

Comment: also, there may have been a misunderstanding of using 'clone' so I've changed the text.

Comment: b/w means "between", at least to me it does. sorry for the confusion. "This will only ADD the listener to the table w/ XX ID".

Answer (score 0):

It's not `$("input[type='select']")`, it's just `$("select")`. `select` is a tag not input type.